# How to find the topics any user follows in twitter with python?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Iam just trying to build a web-application and try to find the **topics any user follows**. I tried to get the timeline and run a *topic-model(classifier)* but it really takes time. Is there any way to find that from *tweepy's* **get_user** function? thnks

Answer (score 0):

i would probably study twitter API
i have developed a Telegram bot, hosted as a google web app, to interface to twitter, and the API was quite rich
good luck

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to find topics that a user *follows* via the Twitter API, but in Twitter API v2, you can discover the topics that are associated with the Tweets a user is posting.

(note that, at the time of posting this answer, Tweepy does not yet support API v2, but they are working on that - there are some Python samples in the [TwitterDev GitHub](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code), which use standard Python libraries where possible to do the work)

The general steps here are:

- have an approved Twitter developer account, and create a new project and app for access to the v2 API
- call the [user Tweet timeline endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/introduction) for the user ID you are interested in, adding the `context_annotations` Tweet field to your request, so that each Tweet is returned with the topic information attached.

This will return data in a format something like this (using the @TwitterDev account as an example):

```js
{
    "data": [
        {
            "context_annotations": [
                {
                    "domain": {
                        "description": "Top level interests and hobbies groupings, like Food or Travel",
                        "id": "65",
                        "name": "Interests and Hobbies Vertical"
                    },
                    "entity": {
                        "description": "Technology and computing",
                        "id": "848920371311001600",
                        "name": "Technology"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "domain": {
                        "description": "A grouping of interests and hobbies entities, like Novelty Food or Destinations",
                        "id": "66",
                        "name": "Interests and Hobbies Category"
                    },
                    "entity": {
                        "description": "Computer programming",
                        "id": "848921413196984320",
                        "name": "Computer programming"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "created_at": "2021-01-05T22:45:35.000Z",
            "id": "1346588685555306497",
            "text": "\ud83d\udd11\ud83d\udd11 On Tuesday, January 12th, we\u2019re removing the ability to view existing consumer API keys from the developer portal. Be sure to save your API keys in a secure place before Tuesday to ensure your access to the #TwitterAPI is not disrupted. Learn more https://twittercommunity.com/t/ability-to-view-existing-consumer-api-keys-being-removed-from-your-developer-dashboard/147849"
        }
...
```

Comment: wow @Andy Piper, thanks for that, till now always used API v1 and constructed an app with that structure. It is good to know that there is a way. For a spaceholder I just scraped all the timeline and get the topics from a topic modelling ML model, but it really take time about 5 sec. and it is too much. thanks again will check and let you know ;)

Comment: This may help https://dev.to/twitterdev/explore-a-user-s-tweets-and-mentions-with-the-twitter-api-v2-274c

Comment: yeah checked yesterday but  facing the authorization problem even if I changed all tokens.

Comment: Is your Twitter app part of an Project inside the developer portal?

Comment: Are you using the Python code sample, or can you share the code you’ve written, and the error message?